# How can I get the input value with onblur event?

Tags: javascript, html, module

I'm trying to get the value input with onblur event and when I use JS modules it doesn't work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
     <head>
          <meta charset="UTF-8" />
          <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
          <title>Calculadora de receitas e despesas</title>
          <script type="module" src="main.js"></script>
     </head>
<body>
  <table> 
      <tr>
               <td >Franchise Fee</td>
               <td class="value">
                    <input type="input" class="form__field" placeholder="R$" name="franchise-fee" id='franchiseFee' onblur="getFranchiseFee()" required />
               </td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</body>
```

GetElements.mjs the module file:

```
function getFranchiseFee(franchiseFee){
    franchiseFee = document.getElementById('franchiseFee');
    // console.log(franchiseFee.value);
    return parseFloat(franchiseFee.value);
}
export {getFranchiseFee};
```

main.js file:

```
import {getFranchiseFee} from './GetElement.mjs';

console.log(getFranchiseFee());
```

I tryed to show on console log the value of the input using the functioin in the module and print using the console log in the main.js file.

Now is showing the error message telling that it is not possible

Comment: why is there an export inside of your function?

Comment: An editor that formats code properly for you as you work will make life much easier.

Comment: why not `change` event?

Comment: I copied wrongly the export here, but now is correct. This was not the problem

Answer (score 0):

I copied wrongly the export here, but now is correct. This was not the problem